# Is there a Windows CMD command to wipe everything?

Tags: windows, wipe

Is there a CMD command like `rm ​-rf --no-​preserve-root` but for Windows? to wipe everything at once.

Comment: Format the drive and that will wipe everything for normal purposes.  You can also just install modern Windows fresh and it will start all over with the required partitions.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I thought maybe there is some kind of command I can use to make process easier. Just tap "enter" and boom, everything is gone. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent command for Windows. Windows is not primarily, or at its core, a CLI OS and so there was no need for this sort of command from the outset.

Both of the core command interpreters in Windows (Command and PowerShell) are not core functions but are "bolted on" so to speak, since the XP days when Windows finished transitioning from its original DOS/MSDOS core. This in some ways limits the ability of what can be done in these programs.

It's possible to take ownership of every file possible, kill every process possible (to minimize files locked by running processes), and then run a strong delete command from the root of the drive, and there's a good chance it would destroy the system, but it would not actually delete all of the system files. The process would get to a point where processes you could not kill would be locking files, and you would not be able to get past this.

The correct way to fully erase a Windows system drive is to use any of the plethora of boot able utilities available, or just use the Windows install process itself.